# Push object data into an array based on another object data value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to push the values based on another value dynamically into an Array Here is my example:

```
const searchData = [
  {
    name: 'Name1',
    value: 'value1',
    class: 'class1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Name1',
    value: 'value2',
    class: 'class2',
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    ID: 'ID1',
    staff: [{ value1: 'hello1', value2: 'hallo1' }],
  },
  {
    ID: 'ID2',
    staff: [{ value1: 'hello2', value2: 'hallo2' }],
  },
];

const array = [];

data.foreach(dataElem => {
  dataElem.staff.foreach(staffElem => {
    searchData.foreach(searchElem => {
      array.push(staffElem[searchElem.value]); // all are undefined -> why?
    )}
  )}
})
```

I don't know why I getting undefined instead of the real values.

Comment: The function is forEach()... check your console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax error logic is right
Compare this with above one

```
data.forEach(dataElem => {
  dataElem.staff.forEach(staffElem => {
    searchData.forEach(searchElem => {
      array.push(staffElem[searchElem.value])
    })
  })
})
```